# Как сделать меню?

Tags: css3, html5

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  /* padding: 0 15px;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* border: 1px solid #ff0 ;*/
}

.ro {
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  background-image: url('../img/logo.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  left: -15%;
  top: 20%;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  /*justify-content: center;*/
  /* align-items: center*/
}

.menu-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex
}

.menu-list2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu__kompani {
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 24px;
}

.menu__kompani:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.menu__item {
  margin-left: 3px;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu__item:first-child {
  margin-left: 0
}

.menu__item2 {
  margin-left: 24px
}

.menu__item2:first-child {
  margin-left: 0
}

.poisk {
  background-color: red;
  width: 23px;
  height: 23px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu__item2_tel {
  color: #fff
}

.aa {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.menu-list3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: #4f4f4f;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #808284;
}

.menu__item3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-right: 1px solid #4e5358;
  padding-right: 17px;
  color: #fff;
}

.m {
  line-height: 20px;
}

.menu__item3_img {
  margin-right: 17px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="ro">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" class='logo__img'>
      </div>
      <div class="menu">
        <span class="menu__kompani">
     О компании 
    </span>
        <span class="menu__kompani">
     Контакты
    </span>
        <ul class="menu-list">
          <li class="menu__item">
            <img src="img/icons/in.png" alt="">
          </li>
          <li class="menu__item">
            <img src="img/icons/youtube.png" alt="">
          </li>
          <li class="menu__item">
            <img src="img/icons/tw.png" alt="">
          </li>
          <li class="menu__item">
            <img src="img/icons/inst.png" alt="">
          </li>
          <li class="menu__item">
            <img src="img/icons/CCl_logo_цветн.png" alt=""> CCL
          </li>
          <li class="menu__item">
            <img src="img/icons/angl.png" alt="">
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="menu-list2">
          <li class="menu__item2 poisk">
            <img src="img/icons/poisk.png" alt="">
          </li>
          <li class="menu__item2">
            <img src="img/icons/Инстаграм_копия.png" alt="">
          </li>
          <li class="menu__item2">
            <span class="menu__item2_tel">
       +7 499 110 58 32
      </span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="aa">
        <ul class="menu-list3">
          <li class="menu__item3">
            <img src="img/RF.png" alt="" class='menu__item3_img'>
            <div class="m">EAS системы </div>
          </li>
          <li class="menu__item3">
            <img src="img/Датчики.png" alt="" class='menu__item3_img'>
            <div class="m">Датчики </div>

          </li>
          <li class="menu__item3">
            <img src="img/Этикетки.png" alt="" class='menu__item3_img'>
            <div class="m">Этикетки </div>

          </li>
          <li class="menu__item3">
            <img src="img/аксессуары.png" alt="" class='menu__item3_img'>
            <div class="m">аксессуары</div>

          </li>
          <li class="menu__item3">
            <img src="img/Исходная_маркировка_st.png" alt="" class='menu__item3_img'>
            <div class="m">Исходная <br>Маркировка ST</div>

          </li>
          <li class="menu__item3">
            <img src="img/RFID.png" alt="" class='menu__item3_img'>
            <div class="m">RFID </div>

          </li>
          <li class="menu__item3">
            <img src="img/Слой_3_копия.png" alt="" class='menu__item3_img'>
            <div class="m">ALS <br> Этикетки</div>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как сделать такое меню ? Пытался ничего не получилось**

Comment: Приведите код ваших попыток. Укажите, что именно не получается.

Comment: @UModeL сейчас, спасибо

Comment: @UModeL вставил

Comment: @UModeL вот ссылка как у меня получилось http://cp62290.tmweb.ru/app/ Помогите сделать как на картинке

Comment: @Air Здравствуйте можете помочь ?

Comment: Привет, а что именно не получается? В чем суть проблемы?

Comment: @Air  картинка и вот ссылка как у меня получилось cp62290.tmweb.ru/app

Comment: @Air  можете помочь ?

Comment: Я могу помочь если пойму, что именно у тебя не получается. Тебя два раза спросили, а ответа так и нет. Или тебе надо, чтобы за тебя меню сверстали  и дали готовый пример? Тут коллеги помогают друг другу, а не работают за других

Comment: @Air меню сверстать как на картинке :((  не получается; я сверстал но не так как на картинке

Comment: @Air вот сравните как на картинке и у меня cp62290.tmweb.ru/app